# Strange behavior with html_escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was writing the helper for my rails app, which should make some manupulations with string, and when I found this. If I use `gsub` method exactly after escaping, then this code doesn't work like I wanted to (it doesn't find the number 999).

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'

text = ">999"

text = ERB::Util.html_escape(text)

# text = text.downcase
text.gsub!(/\&gt\;(\d+)/) { "found [#{$1}]" }

puts text
```

In another case, if I uncomment `text = text.downcase`, i.e. apply any method to string, then all works fine. So what should I do if I would like to use `gsub` exactly after `html_escape` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting an awesome feature; try this:

```
# ...as before.
text = ERB::Util.html_escape(text)
puts text.class
```

`text` is actually an instance of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, which presumably implements the `gsub!` method, takes a block, but gets it somehow wrong - in that it doesn't result in `$1` being set.

You can work around this by way of either:

```
text = text.to_s.gsub!(...)
text = text.gsub!(...) {|match| "found [#{match}]" }
```

You might find this inconsistency fixed in a later version of the ActiveSupport code, but otherwise you might as well file the bug report now; that `gsub!` behaviour is well documented and should be preserved.